# Is there a difference in meaning between "reliquiis in locis" and "alibi"?

Tags: adverb, gaius-iulius-caesar

Caesar wrote in De Bello Gallico: "*Ea nascuntur alces, animalia quae **reliquis in locis** visa non sint.*". Why didn't he simply write "*alibi*" there? Is there a difference in meaning? And why doesn't "in" go before "*reliquiis*"? Did he maybe mean "*by other (people) in (other) places*"?

Comment: If your text has *reliquiis* rather than *reliquis* it's wrong.

Comment: @Cairnarvon What is the difference? Is *reliquiis* a noun and *reliquis* an adjective, or?

Comment: *Reliquis* is from the adjective *reliquus* 'remaining', *reliquiis* would have to be from the noun *reliquiae* 'remains' (a plurale tantum).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is the same as the difference between "elsewhere" and "in other places" in English. Latin is a language, it has multiple ways to express a given concept.

Single-syllable prepositions, and especially *cum*, *dē*, *ex*, and *in*, will often be placed between the adjective and noun following it. You can see this as a kind of hyperbaton if you like, but it's idiomatic and very common.

*Reliquis in locis* is definitely a coherent prepositional phrase, and *reliquis* cannot mean "by others"—an ablative of personal agent requires a preposition *ab*/*ā*.